# Coding 4 fun library does not import Controller Class

Tags: windows-phone-8, toast

I am trying to show toast message in foreground(while app is running).So i tried using  Coding 4 fun library for this.But i can't seem to import controller class thus i am unable to create ToastPromt.I did install complete Coding 4 fun library with NuGet Package installer.

Btw I am making windows phone 8.0 project

[image: no controller class]

Comment: why not use the pushnotification recieved event handler and create a toast manually and display ??? just a suggestion :-)

Comment: I am a beginner mobile developer.I do not know how to do that,It would be great if you can suggest some resources for that.And i do not understand why is it this hard to show just a simple message box(toast or similiar) in WP8,it very simple in android

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709907.aspx

check this link

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465448.aspx

use this for displaying the toast notification in the proper conditional statement